# Interrupting application flow from a non-MVC event

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm working on an application which uses a REST API backend. This API has a login step which creates a token used for all subsequent API requests. I store this token in the auth storage, and I have an event hook that checks if the user is logged in, and if not, renders the login page:

```
$eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE, function($e) use ($view, $auth) {
    $match = $e->getRouteMatch();

    // No route match, this is a 404
    if (!$match instanceof RouteMatch) {
        return;
    }

    // Route is whitelisted
    $matchedRoute = $match->getMatchedRouteName();
    if (in_array($matchedRoute, array('login'))) {
        return;
    }

    // if they're logged in, all is good
    if ($auth->hasIdentity()) {
        return true;
    }

    [render login form and return response object]
}, -100);
```

This works great.

The API also sometimes expires the login tokens in a way that I can't easily predict, which means all API calls will return a 'Session expired' type error. I've written an event trigger after the API calls that I can hook into. I want to check for these 'session expired' responses and somehow render the login page in the same way I do above:

```
$events->attach('Api', 'call', function ($e) {
    $api = $e->getTarget();
    $params = $e->getParams();

    $result = $params['apiResult'];

    if ([result is a session expired response]) {
        // what can I do here?
    }

}, 999);
```

but since this isn't an MVC event, even if I could access the response object here, returning it wouldn't do anything. What would be the best way to interrupt the application flow in a non-MVC event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I'm assuming that your API events do occur in a dedicated `EventManager` instance (so your API may be an implementation of `EventManagerAwareInterface`) and not in the MVC one (which is the one you grab from the `Zend\Mvc\Application` instance).

If that's the case, you could inject both the main `EventManager` and the `MvcEvent` inside your API, and then short circuit the MVC cycle from the `call` listener.

I.e. assume your dependencies are in `$mvcEvent` and `$mvcEventManager` properties with getters, this is how you would listen for the `call` event:

```
$events->attach('call', function($e) {
    $api = $e->getTarget();
    $params = $e->getParams();

    $result = $params['apiResult'];

    if ([result is a session expired response]) {
        $mvcEvent = $api->getMvcEvent();
        $mvcEvent->setError('api error');
        $mvcEvent->setParam('exception', new \Exception('Session expired'));
        $api->getMvcEventManager()->trigger('dispatch.error', $mvcEvent);
    }

}, 999);
```

There are better ways to do it for sure, choosing the best will depend on the architecture of your API class.

You could use `Zend\EventManager\ResponseCollection` returned by your trigger, rather than using the MVC event inside the listener; that would enable your API event cycle to continue even if some error occurs. That's actually how `Zend\Mvc\Application` uses its own event manager in the `run()` method, so you can peek at that for an example.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I've implemented your solution by passing the MvcEvent and the main EventManager into the Api class and triggering a dispatch error as in your example. But this really just gives me a more user friendly error message, I don't think I can do much with the response object here so I might need to rethink my approach.

Comment: Well using the 'dispatch.error' was just an example. You could do all sort of things, i.e. setting a RouteMatch in the MvcEvent and trigger a 'dispatch' to your login controller action.